How to properly set cluster_id
I want to specify an explicit cluster_id, e.g 'abc'
I created a profile 'test' and edited ipcontroller_config.py, setting
c.BaseParallelApplication.cluster_id = 'abc' 

When I run ipcluster start --profile=test from the command line, everything goes well, and the files cluster-abc.json, ipcontroller-abc-client.json and ipcontroller-abc-engine.json are created in profile_test/security.
Now, when I open python and run:
from ipyparallel import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(profile="test")
cluster.start_cluster_sync()

it hangs (it does not if I do not modify c.BaseParallelApplication.cluster_id), and the files created in profile_test/security are named cluster-1712599063-udeb.json (or any other random name), ipcontroller-abc-client.jsonand ipcontroller-abc-engine.json.
If I edit rather ipcluster_config.py (what I did first as it seemed more logical), it is simply not taken into account, the cluster id is set randomly.
What am I missing?
